# Liferay : can we use Liferay Hooks for Modfying Liferay Login pre and Post events

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6 .

I have read that Liferay Hooks can be used to modify  JSP , Property files , Model Listeners , System Events , without touching Liferay code at all .

So my question is that can i use Liferay Hooks for Modfying Liferay Login pre and Post events ??

Please specify .

Thank you .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  What you want to do is specify a portal.properties file in a hook project and then set the following properties:

```
login.events.pre=
login.events.post=
```

[See more documentation here.](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/extending-and-overriding-%3Cem%3Eportal-properties%3C-e-1)